# Global Function not returning the correct values

Tags: c, function, global-variables

I'm trying to compile the first non zero value of a vector, using a global function. But as I compile, it returns the original value k1=k2=1, when it's supposed to be k1=0 and k2=2. No? My code looks like this:

````
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int primeiro(float vec[], int f)
{
  f=0;

    while(vec[f]==0)
    {
     f++;
    }

 return f;
}


int main()

{
float poli1[4]={1,2,3,4}, poli2[4]={0,0,5,6};
int k1=1, k2=1, i;

printf(" \n");

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
     printf("%g\t", poli1[i]);
  }

printf("\n \n");

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
     printf("%g\t", poli2[i]);
  }

printf("\n \n");

primeiro(poli1, k1);
printf("%d \n", k1);
primeiro(poli2, k2);
printf("%d \n", k2);
                
}```
````

Comment: You are not storing the return value of the calls to `primeiro` so how do you expect that to change any of the variables? Also, remember that C function args are passed *by value* - function args are local to the function and changing that inside the function has no effect on the caller's variable value.

Comment: Perhaps you want `k1 = primeiro(poli1, k1);`? Or pass in the second arg as a pointer so that it can dereference and modify the original variable value.

Comment: ooo I think I undertand yes, thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You never change `k1` and `k2`, so they have their original value.

Maybe

```c
primeiro(poli1, k1);
primeiro(poli2, k2);
```

was meant to be

```c
k1 = primeiro(poli1, k1);
k2 = primeiro(poli2, k2);
```

Comment: yep, it worked as you said, and that's even better tbh, I won't need to execute the function every time hehe @ikegami

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use pass-by-reference (pointers) to change value of k1 in your main code (the scope where it exits) or assign the inovcation of primeiro to k1 9k1 = primeiro(poli1, k1);) which is actually returning value from it.

Revised implementation:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int primeiro(float vec[], int f)
{
  f=0;

    while(vec[f]==0)
    {
     f++;
    }

 return f;
}


int main()

{
float poli1[4]={1,2,3,4}, poli2[4]={0,0,5,6};
int k1=1, k2=1, i;

printf(" \n");

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
     printf("%g\t", poli1[i]);
  }

printf("\n \n");

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
     printf("%g\t", poli2[i]);
  }

printf("\n \n");

k1 = primeiro(poli1, k1);
printf("%d \n", k1);
k2 = primeiro(poli2, k2);
printf("%d \n", k2);
```